# Which design pattern should be used to pass data to global view

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I have one label which is added on window. I have added a timer on my view class which updates the data by calling model method. Now if I move to another view controller my timer will do its work of updating data.

Now my question is what is the right way to update label text?

I can do it by using delegation pattern where my custom Label will be the delegate and model will be the delegator. Will it the right approach?

Comment: If you are trying to change label's text of one particular view from one particular VC then delegation is best approach. But if you want to change the text from all of your VCs then UNNotificationCenter will be the best approach to work with.

Comment: I would suggest that the timer should be part of your model and that the model could use a `Notification` to let interested observers know about a change in the property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you add a ViewContoller’s view to the window, and add tile label to that view. It’s the VC’s job to notice the the timer has fired, update the model, notice that the model has changed and update it’s views (and their subviews) to match the new state.

Comment: Yeah. agreed but in my case this label will be shown to all view controllers of my app and removed when disable by a controller.

Comment: @user1101733, what that sounds like to me, then, is that your app's view controllers *share* a portion of their behavior with respect to a portion of their views.  The concise way to give these VCs this common data and behavior is through inheritance.